# Read, write csv files across different directories

Tags: python, csv, operating-system, glob

I have a Python file located in folder C:\D1\D1a\D1b. Another folder, say C:\D2\D2a\D2b contains a few csv files created at different times.
First step, I need to find the most recent csv file from folder C:\D2\D2a\D2b. 
Second step, I have to open that particular csv file (with csv.reader) and perform some calculations based on its content.
My program works very well if the csv files are in the same folder with the python file, but breaks down when I try to work across different folders. The two folders can be located in arbitrary locations in the computer.
My system is Win10 and I prefer a simple solution within python.
The simplified code is:

```
import csv
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('C:\D2\D2a\D2b\*.csv')
print('found csv files:',list_of_files)
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getmtime)
print('The most recent .csv file found:',latest_file,'\n')

with open('latest_file',newline='') as DAQfile:
    reader=csv.reader(DAQfile,delimiter=',')
    i=0
    for row in reader:
        i+=1
    rows=i
print(rows)
```

The output is:

```
found csv files: ['C:\\D2\\D2a\\D2b\\Book1.csv', 'C:\\D2\\D2a\\D2b\\Book2.csv']
The most recent .csv file found: C:\D2\D2a\D2b\Book2.csv 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\D1\D1a\D1b\Mytest.py", line 10, in <module>
    with open('latest_file',newline='') as DAQfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latest_file'
```

Comment: `with open('latest_file',newline='') as DAQfile:` passes `latest_file` as a string literal, not the name of the variable. Remove the quotes. I'm not sure if that will fix your code, but it's one issue.

Answer (score 0):

Oops! It appears that the quotation marks around *latest_file* in the *open* statement were causing the problem. It works now.